# success:function(data) alert empty using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hi i have this messaging system. I am using ajax in sending the messages. The messages works well and will able to saved in the database too.when i refresh the whole page the messages is there. My problem is i want that when i input the messages and click reply the messages will prepend to the corresponding html `<div>` now that when i `alert(data)` it seems it is empty. Here is my ajax code below

```
$.ajax({
              type: "get",
              url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/messages/reply'?>",
              data: {
                replyMessage:replyMessage,
                adminId:adminId,
                getUserId:getUserId,
                msgId:msgId
              },
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#success").show();
                $("#replyMessage").val('');
                $("#success").fadeOut(3000);
                $(data).prependTo('conversation-item item-right clearfix').show();
              }
            });
```

And my reply function

```
 public function reply(){
      $uri = $this->uri->segment(5);

            $msgId = $this->input->post('msgId');

      $adminId = $this->input->post('adminId');
      $replyMessage = $this->input->post('replyMessage');
      $getUserId = $this->input->post('getUserId');

      $dateCreated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      $array = array(
              'userId'=>$adminId,
              'message'=>$replyMessage,
              'senderId'=>$getUserId,
                            'msgId'=>$msgId,
              'dateCreated'=>$dateCreated
              );
      $this->mm->sendMessage($array);
      $id = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    }
```

and my views page

```
<?php foreach($getThreadMessage as $thread): ?>
                    <div class="conversation-item item-right clearfix">
                        <div class="conversation-user">
                          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/small_empty_image.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conversation-body">
                          <div class="name">
                            <?php echo ucwords($thread->firstName); ?> <?php echo ucwords($thread->lastName); ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="time hidden-xs">
                            <?php echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($thread->dateUpdated)); ?>
                            <?php echo date('H:i a', strtotime($thread->dateUpdated)); ?>

                          </div>
                          <div class="text">
                            <?php echo $thread->message;?>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Comment: add `echo $replyMessage;` at the end of `reply()` function.

Comment: ok ill try your code

Comment: nothing happened the alert(data) is empty

Comment: ok it works but my prepend doesnt work
 $(data).prependTo('.conversation-item item-right clearfix').show();

Comment: it will not work.. you have to do like `$(".conversation-item item-right clearfix").prependTo(data).show();`

Comment: ok ill try your code

Comment: ive tried your code its not working

Comment: try to make it working.. any error ? any warning? What you have tried to debug so far?

Comment: yes i tried to debug on it no error and no warning too

Comment: try to locate.. why `prepandTo` not working? see documentation. try examples of prepandTo,

Comment: ok thanks ill try to look for it

Answer (score 0):

In your controller after the code `$id = $this->db->insert_id();`

add this code

```
$data['getThreadMessage'] = $this->mm->get_message($id);
        print($this->load->view("getThreadMessage-view", $data));
```

YOu have create a function `get_message($id);` in the model `mm` and create a view  with name `getThreadMessage-view`

getThreadMessage-view

```
<div class="conversation-item item-right clearfix">
                        <div class="conversation-user">
                          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/small_empty_image.png" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conversation-body">
                          <div class="name">
                            <?php echo ucwords($thread->firstName); ?> <?php echo ucwords($thread->lastName); ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="time hidden-xs">
                            <?php echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($thread->dateUpdated)); ?>
                            <?php echo date('H:i a', strtotime($thread->dateUpdated)); ?>

                          </div>
                          <div class="text">
                            <?php echo $thread->message;?>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in jquery success function

```
 $(".conversation-item.item-right.clearfix").prepend(data);
```

Comment: you code works but i want to prepend the data after sending the messages

Comment: hi this things works 
$(".conversation-item.item-right.clearfix").prepend(data);
but all of the foreach will write

Comment: `$data['getThreadMessage'] = $this->mm->get_message($id);` change this to `$data['getThreadMessage'] = $this->mm->get_message();` get all message.. and `foreach` in view

Comment: i will attach a screencast in here